# How do I use increment in calculations?

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

```
{int num1 = 5;
 int num2 = 6;
 int num3;
 num3 = ++num2 * num1 / num2 + num2;
 System.out.println(num3);} //12
```

The compiler gives the num3 = 12, but how do I get that value? when I try to get that num3 value I got 6(by without using compiler). Both value of num2++ and ++num2 gives the same, but when I use following code it gives a different value. Why I got different values. what are the steps for get those num3 values (without using compiler?)

```
num3 = num2++ * num1 / num2 + num2; //11
```

Comment: Brackets my friend brackets. Remeber BODMAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both increment operation `num++` and `++num` will result into `num=num+1` there is only difference between the order of `assignment` and `increment` operations.

`num++(post-increment) -> first num is used and then incremented
++num(pre-increment) -> first num is incremented and then used`

You code prints `12` when I tested.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 6;
        int num3;
        num3 = ++num2 * num1 / num2 + num2;
        System.out.println(num3);
    }
```

I will suggest you to make use of brackets as it will increase readability as well.

Comment: first one is 12 and second one is 11 no

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
int num2 = 6;
System.out.println(num2++);
```

It will print 6, and then change num2 to 7. But if you do:

```
int num2 = 6;
System.out.println(++num2);
```

It will change num2 to 7 and then print 7. So:

```
num3 = ++num2 * num1 / num2 + num2;
num3 = 7 * 5/ 7 + 7
num3 = 35/7 + 7
num3 = 12
```